# Spring : PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cannot find property file

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath, osgi

I have a strange problem with Spring using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. One of my beans is designed as follow :

```
<bean name="propertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that spring never find jdbc.properties (`FileNotFoundException`). The file is in a folder named "resources" that is in the bundle classpath (I am working in a OSGi project).

I have tried almost every combination ("jdbc.properties", "/jdbc.properties", "classpath:jdbc.properties", "classpath:/jdbc.properties", "/resources/jdbc.properties", etc...) but it never works.

For information, if at some point, I do something like :

```
URL u = someClassLoader.getResource("jdbc.properties");
```

it does work without any problem and find the file. Actually I am totally unable to understand what is the bug with spring.

If you have any idea to help me, thanks in advance. I am not very experienced in spring so I have maybe done a mistake somewhere.

[EDIT]

Actually, it's a problem of classloader :
If I do :

```
new ClassPathResource("jdbc.properties");
```

it doesn't work. But :

```
new ClassPathResource("jdbc.properties",someClassIntheBundle.class.getClassLoader());
```

works perfectly.

I do believe that Spring use the ClassLoader of its own bundle that is consumed by my bundle. Do you know a way to solve this tricky problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: For the moment, I have to put awful static path in my config-file for testing (like bundleresource://63.jhdjlzeo:2/jdbc.properties (it works with it)). I haven't find any other solution (cf. other comments infra)

Answer (score 1):

try `classpath*:jdbc.properties`

Comment: Actually, it does not complain anymore but it does not find the location as well :s Thanks in all cases for your help. Do you know what is the main difference with classpath: ?

Comment: Sorry about long answer. You can find it in spring [references](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html). And, of course you can create sub-class of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and load prop files using `MyConfigurer.class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

IANA OSGI developer, but a quick Google search results in a [link](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/bnd-app-ctx.html) to the Spring-osgi documentation. Look at section 5.4 and note that the spring-osgi package makes some changes to `Resource` loading. It looks like the `ResourceLoader` implemented by the default `ApplicationContext` for osgi will automatically pre-pend `osgibundle:` if no other prefix is provided.

It appears as though there is some difference in scope between the path searched when using `classpath:` and the path used when using `classpath*:`, but I have so far been unable to find a good explanation for it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had probably missed it. There are some "strange" things that I need to investigate in all cases (with classpath*:, it does find the property file but then it's still unable to resolve placeholders. It may not be linked at all but I am not sure...

Comment: @ThR37: I'm unable to find documentation for it currently, but I do seem to remember that there was a shortcoming in property token resolution when properties loaded in a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in a parent `ApplicationContext` were referenced from an `import`ed `ApplicationContext`.